# RemoveExistingProducts and InstallExecute action

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I came across the following suggestion in [this](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/wix-developers-guide-windows-installer-xml) book,

> If you schedule RemoveExistingProducts after InstallInitialize, you
>   must also schedule the InstallExecute action to run after it.

This is in the context of a Major upgrade. But the author doesn't elaborate why one must do this. What is the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN docs for RemoveExistingProducts say that's what you must do, so that's one reason. It points out that the usual sequence with InstallExecute is  InstallExecute, RemoveExistingProducts, and InstallFinalize. Otherwise REP needs to happen before there are any actual changes to the system, which is why **immediately** after InstallInitialize or InstallValidate are legal sequence choices, that's the more obscure rule about "before script actions that alter the system".

The other reason is that InstallExecute makes sure that the install transaction is complete, so you're not uninstalling the old product when the newly installed upgrade isn't fully complete and REP is before InstallFinalize.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369502(v=vs.85).aspx

So in summary, REP needs to be sequenced before anything is done to the system or after all the required changes have been committed with InstallExecute if it's in the transaction. Also, if it's inside the transaction then it's included in the rollback which will reinstall the older product being upgraded. REP after InstallFinalize means that the uninstall can fail and roll back, reinstalling the product resulting in old and new products on the system.

The documentation you quoted saying"after InstallInitialize" does not adequately cover all the possibilities, because after InstallFinalize does not mean that InstallExecute is required. It may have been taken out of context but the MSDN docs are fairly complete.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it somehow, but I'm looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371197(v=vs.85).aspx and can't seem to find direct verbiage, maybe it's implied?

Comment: I'm not sure about "... so you're not uninstalling the old product when the newly installed upgrade isn't fully complete." Per my understanding, the placement of REP after InstallInitialize means that the old version of the product will be removed completely before the new one is installed. Of course, since REP is being scheduled in the deferred phase there will be rollback to the old version if installation of new version fails.

Comment: If you were to say "immediately after InstallInitialize"  I'd agree, but InstallExecute-REP-InstallFinalize is also after InstallInitialize, and in this case the new product has already been installed. I've expanded the answer because "after InstallInitialize" covers all documented uses of REP, and InstallExecute certainly isn't needed for all of them.